# How do I use pseudo-classes to select all children except first and last?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

In CSS, for the example shown below, how can I make it such that the styles get applied to all paragraphs, except for the first and the last paragraph?

```
<div class="entry">
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
</div>
```

I've tried the following to exclude the first paragraph, but that doesn't work:

```
div.entry p:nth-child(n+1) {
    /* ... */
}
```

I've also tried `nth-of-type()` and `not()`, but couldn't get them to work the way I thought they would.

Edit: I've decided to wrap all the `<p>`s which I want to apply the style to in a `<div>`. I've accepted bozdoz answer, because it came the closest to solving the original problem (even though it solved only half of it).

Comment: See where they're supported first: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Updated answer:

Use both `:not(:first-child)` and `:not(:last-child)`

```
div.entry p:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)
```

See updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/PA6yp/64/).

Comment: I'm not sure why this received 8 upvotes - it only addresses half of the question, which is to say the "except for the first" portion, and completely ignores the other half of the question.

Comment: Updated.  Solves both halves of the problem now. @BoltClock I also ponder the mystery of SO answers: some undeserved get huge upvotes, and some extremely deserved get few, and some decent get downvotes.  Honestly almost made me quit answering questions on SO.  Users are often cruel and unusual.

Comment: Editing your answer to someone elses more correct answer doesn't quite seem fitting.

Comment: It's the correct answer.  I answered the first half of it already.  I honestly didn't see yours, if it helps. @WORMSS

Comment: @WORMSS: I'm on the fence here. I probably would have thought of the exact same solution myself. There are many ways to skin a cat, of course, e.g. an alternative that's more in line with the original answer would be `:not(:nth-child(1)):not(:nth-last-child(1))`. But then that just seems needlessly verbose when `:first-child` and `:last-child` already exist. I don't think he had any intention on copying your answer.

Comment: But he had his answer here for 2 years that only answered half of the OP question. 10 hours after I add my answer, his mysteriously changes. (Again after 2 years) to my answer.

Comment: I edited my answer because of BoltClock's comment.  I didn't even see OP's edit saying that I answered half.  I assume this question got bumped because of it or some other edit, and I also assume that's the reason you answered @WORMSS

Comment: Nope, it was my answer that caused the bump.

Comment: Didn't realize, @WORMSS. I was just trying to keep BoltClock from being mad at me.  If it's any consolation, I did give you +1.  Not much else I can do.

Answer (score 2):

I know I am late to the game on this, but I thought I would just add this for any future viewers.

`div.entry p:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)`

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled across something that might answer your question:

> To represent **all h2 children** of an XHTML body **except the first and
>   last**, one could use the following selector:
>
> `body > h2:nth-of-type(n+2):nth-last-of-type(n+2)`

[W3C - CSS3-Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-last-of-type-pseudo)