# CSS how to use pseudo-class :not with :nth-child

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is is possible to use `:not()` with  `nth-child` ?

I tried something like this without any luck :

```
td:not(:nth-child(4n)){
  text-align:center;
}
```

However this seems to work :

```
td:not(:first-child){
  text-align:center;
}
```

What I am trying is to center align all table columns except 2nd and 4th column. The columns are dynamically generated to add a custom class to these column .

Comment: Where is your HTML contents? Create [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net) atleast

Comment: Your `:not(:nth-child(4n))` selector works fine on Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/v7tBd

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Works also in Firefox

Comment: @Rahil Wazir, as I said the content is generated dynamically

Comment: Try this link..........................

[Click here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067792/css-pseudo-classes-nth-child-nth-of-type-not

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15448679/using-nth-child-in-tables-tr-td this is a similar post. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vQW6T/

Answer (score 100, accepted):

`:not(:nth-child(4n))` will get you anything that isn't `:nth-child(4n)`, i.e. anything that isn't the 4th, 8th and so on. It won't exclude the 2nd child because 2 isn't a multiple of 4.

To exclude the 2nd and 4th you need either one of:

- `td:not(:nth-child(2n))` if you have fewer than 6 columns, or
- `td:not(:nth-child(2)):not(:nth-child(4))` if you have at least 6 columns and only want to exclude the 2nd and 4th, and not every even column.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/a9CR7/)

Comment: Was late for the party, anyways I had made a fiddle with `nth-of-type` but modified as per your selector, +1...

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using "not", the default approach in CSS is to override styles:

```
td {
    text-align: center;
}
td:first-child {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Can somebody comment what's not ok with that, instead of just downgrading?

Comment: because your CSS will left align the text on the first column and center the rest, which doesn't fit OP's requirements. OP wants to center align the text on every column except the 2nd and 4th one.