# CSS to untarget certain element?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

What is the correct selector to un-target a div inside a div based on position that is un-target 1st child div or 2nd child, and so on.

For example,

```
<div class="myclass">
 <div>1st
   <div>Child of 1st</div>
 </div>

 <div>2nd</div>
 <div>3rd</div>
</div>
```

If I want class myclass not to apply to  nth child of 1st?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21829478/css-how-to-use-pseudo-class-not-with-nth-child](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21829478/css-how-to-use-pseudo-class-not-with-nth-child)

Comment: "I want class myclass not to apply to nth child of 1st" But that div *doesn't* have "myclass". Your markup clearly shows that only the top-level div has "myclass". I suspect your choice of words is wrong there. What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: @Dippas Actually, I'm not seeing how this is a dup of the referenced question. I cannot see how the approach there works on multiple levels. If you use `:not(first-child) :not(first-child)` { color: red; } to "de-select" the first grandchild, the first `:not` will cause the selector to not apply to the entire first branch. I don't see any way in this case other than to write a separate rule for `:first-child > :first-child`, which is probably the best way to handle it anyway. The only alternative would be to write `:first-child > :not(:first-child), :not(:first-child) > *` which seems verbose.

Comment: I find myself don't know English...

Comment: @torazaburo that's because OP changed markup in the question after I marked as duplicated, it is now opened ;)

Answer (score 0):

You probably could have googled this first. Select n-th child:

```
    div > div:nth-child(2) {
        background: red;
    }
```

Unselect n-th child:

```
    div > div:not(:nth-child(2)) {
        background: red;
    }
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uk0vnycw/

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: OP want to avoid class on the nth element not add.

Comment: @TheYaXxE I was missing some parentheses when @Teshtek commented. Anyway, I just re-read op's question. Are you using jQuery? It occurs to me that you want to *remove* `myclass` for the n-th div. I don't know anyway of doing this with pure css